# How to integrate google maps in android application to show nearest places with GPS?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, gps

I'm creating an Android application to show nearest fuel stations using GPS coordinates for our public service. I don't know how to show nearest fuel station according to GPS coordinates and show in map in Android application. I'm trying it with Xamarin and C# but I think the concept of integrating the map will be same. Kindly help if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a comment but still got not enough rep so this is an answer:

You can use geofence for this.
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html